# Select DBNULL in SQL with User Defined Table Type

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a litte project where i need to select data depending on whether the string `customerId` is contained in a User Defined Table Type `customerTable` or not. I managed to get it to work so that when the `customerId` is contained in the `customerTable` the data is shown. But in my view table there are also some unknown customers where the `customerId` is `DBNULL`. How can I manage to select them, when the customerTable contains the VARCHAR(MAX) 'Select All'?

`customerTable` just contains one column with VARCHAR(MAX) `customer`

My currently working code:

```
@customers PatientTable READONLY

SELECT item 
FROM dbo.customerTable
WHERE customerId IN (SELECT customer FROM @customers)
```

I hope you are able to understand my problem now.
Thanks in advance

Greets

Comment: I thought about some IF-ELSE Like Statement in the WHERE clause. When 'Select All' then return the whole view else only the customers in the Table

Comment: what is @patients for, you don't use it?

Comment: Oh this was me forgetting to edit it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT item 
FROM dbo.customerTable
WHERE ISNULL(customerId,'') IN (SELECT Customer FROM @customers)
```

Take a look at

## [ISNULL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,198593)